# scrollview can't scroll when focus textinput react native

Tags: android-edittext, react-native, scrollview, textinput, react-native-scrollview

I have a TextInput inside a ScrollView.

The scroll isn't working when the TextInput is on focus. This problem is only affecting Android.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: I had a problem with this and it turned out that it was because I was specifying a height in the styles for the TextInput, but the contents of the TextInput were exceeding that height in Android but not iOS (because the system fonts were overriding my font styles). In case anyone else comes across this it can be fixed by removing the hard coded height or increasing it to ensure that it can contain the content without overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

setting

`<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`

in combination with the textInput component below (custom component that i created for text inputs to solve this issue) solved my problem:

```
<TouchableOpacity
     activeOpacity={1}
     onPress={()=>this.input.focus()}>
     <View pointerEvents="none"
           <TextInput
              ref = {(input) => this.input = input}
           />
     </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Warning: this method effectively disables text selection, so users are not able to copy/paste or place the cursor in the middle of the text.

Comment: @DavidJones exactly, That's the problem. Have you found any solution to that?

Comment: (Sorry, it won't let me @ mention your username, so hopefully you see this.) In my case this was being caused by the alignment of the input text—the issue appears when the text is center-aligned or right-aligned. This is a known bug: (see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25594 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25594). The only workaround I know of is to set `multiline={true}`.

Comment: Could you take a look at this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Comment: @Jnl I provided a solution for you. take a look and let me know if your problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

In scrollView use ***keyboardShouldPersistTaps***

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
```

it solve your problem

check docs here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboarddismissmode

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem on Android.

Comment: Could you take a look at this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior.

For more information [Official TextInput documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)

You might want to try something like this: [react-native-kayboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

Answer (score 1):

i use simple trick for `TextInput` and that work for me correctly .Should add this `prop` in `TextInput` :

```
<TextInput
      multiline={true}
      numberOfLines={1}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good example: http://blog.arjun.io/react-native/mobile/cross-platform/2016/04/01/handling-the-keyboard-in-react-native.html

The thing that was really important for me was to add:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

in AndroidManifest.xml in order to focus the textInput

Answer (score 0):

I handle in different ways to each platform (in Ios focus to inputText is enough, 
don't forget to put `this.scrollViewRef` ref inside `ScrollView` that wrap inputText and put ref index the inputText

```
if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
    this.inputRefs[field].measure((w, h, px, py, xPage, yPage) => {
        this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: yPage, animated: true })
        this.inputRefs[field].focus()
    })
} 
this.inputRefs[field].focus()
```