# TextInput prevents ScrollView from scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a form that is longer than the phone's screen height. It is a `ScrollView` containing `TextInput` components. The problem is that when I want to drag starting the touch on a `TextInput`, the `ScrollView` doesn't move. If I drag starting on a blank space (the `View` in the code example), it scrolls perfectly.

It feels like the `TextInput` is somehow eating the touch/drag event, not allowing the `ScrollView` to interact.

The `ScrollView` looks similar to this:

```
function Form() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, }}>
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <View style={{ height: 150, }} />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
            <TextInput placeholder="test" />
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

How can I make the scrolling work?

**Update**: I noticed that when I start scrolling on the blank space, I can then keep scrolling by touching the inputs. However, as soon as the inertia stops, I'm unable to scroll using the inputs again.

Comment: Still happening in `react-native: 0.47.2`

Comment: Still happening in `react-native: 0.60`

Comment: As quoted here:TextInput prevent scroll on ScrollView #25594 textAlign="center" causes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so looks like this is a bug in the 0.32 version of React Native library. Scrolling works as expected in 0.33. It was solved by [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/db1b0e9be9c286743769bfbb7d7eef1231ed43b4).

Comment: Have the same problem in 0.39.2.

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version if you can. You're ten versions behind :/

Comment: it's still not working , there is a visible sroll in textInput itself

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue. It turns out, this is only the case if `TextInput` component is given an implicit `height` style, which forces it to shrink down, and start capturing scroll events. I removed it and managed my `TextInput` size via `fontSize` and `padding` and it solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: this might help - [scrollview can't scroll when focus textinput react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745442/scrollview-cant-scroll-when-focus-textinput-react-native?rq=1)**

Could it be the missing `<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>` wrapping around the `<ScrollView>` ?

I tried this and it scrolls fine from both the inner View and the TextInput components:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} >
                <TextInput placeholder="this is a textinput with height 200" style={{ borderColor: 'brown', borderWidth: 1, height: 200 }} />
                <TextInput placeholder="this is a textinput with height 1200" style={{ borderColor: 'brown', borderWidth: 1, height: 1200 }} />
                <View style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'khaki' }} />
                <TextInput placeholder="this is a textinput with height 200" style={{ borderColor: 'brown', borderWidth: 1, height: 200 }} />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

But since you're saying that it scrolls when dragging from the View component, maybe sharing the entire code might reveal something

Comment: Thanks, but adding the `View` did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, I've faced the same problem and found no public workaround.

In my case the reason was in `TextInput` `height` style property **not** been set explicitly. Without it (or with `flex: 1` set, nevermind) the *actual height* of the input field can be *slightly less then the height of it's text*, forcing the text to scroll vertically (even though `multiline` style is `false`, `scrollEnabled` is `false`, etc.).

So, my solution is to explicitly set the minimal `height` value that will let the whole text to fit.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted here:[TextInput prevent scroll on ScrollView #25594](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25594) `textAlign="center"` causes this problem.

Adding `multiline={true}` with `style={{textAlign: "center"}}` resolve the problem.

Comment: But I don't want to center align it

Answer (score 0):

import ScrollView and TextInput from 'react-native' not from 'react-native-gesture-handler'